# How can I know if a number is inside a list in PARI/GP?

Tags: pari

I am trying to know if a number is inside a PARI/GP list but I do not know how to do it, this is my code:

```
mylist = listcreate();

... here I add some numbers with  listput(mylist,XXXX)

/* How can I do the condition in the if... */
if(mynumber in mylist,print("SUCCESS"),print("ERROR"))
```

I am migrating from Python to PARI/GP some of my scripts and I am lost in those basic things, [the manual](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/Vectors,_matrices,_linear_algebra_and_sets.html) is a little bit difficult to follow. Thank you!

Comment: Please, see the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753897/finding-entry-of-vector-in-pari-gp/29568708#29568708. Note, you need not the "index mode" there.

Comment: @PiotrSemenov thank you! indeed I have read the question and your answer before, but it talks about vectors, not lists, so I thought it was not possible to use it with lists.

Comment: Small remark is here just in case :) Function `select` from PARI/GP 2.7.3 (recent release) works well with lists. Please, see how to check if a random list contains a number `10`: `lst = List(vector(1000,i,random(100))); select((e) -> e == 10, lst) != []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if a given value is in a list, vector, or column vector like so:

```
inList(list, value)=for(i=1,#list, if(list[i]==value, return(i))); 0
```

or less efficiently like

```
inlist(list, value)=#select(n->n==value, list) > 0
```

Your example would then look like

```
if(inList(mylist, mynumber), print("SUCCESS"), print("ERROR"))
```

But if you're going to be doing a lot of queries, it's worthwhile to use a binary search instead:

```
myset = Set(mylist);
if(setsearch(myset, mynumber), print("SUCCESS"), print("ERROR"))
```

Comment: @iadvd: No problem -- I'll do what I can for all the [tag:pari] and [tag:pari-gp] questions. :)